# Python matrix column and row check

Tags: python, matrix, tic-tac-toe

I have been working on dynamic tic tac toe game
And when checking rows and columns I faced up with a problem.

Fist of all my table looks like;

```
size? : 4 #input
  0   1   2   3 
  4   5   6   7 
  8   9  10  11 
 12  13  14  15 
Player 1 plays :
```

And I am checking if columns are full with X or O's

```
def column_check():
col_winner = None
cx = []
co = []
for i in range(1):
    for j in range(0, game_size ** 2, game_size):
        if matrix[j] == player1:
            cx.append(j)
        elif matrix[j] == player2:
            co.append(j)

if len(cx) == game_size:
    col_winner = player1
elif len(co) == game_size:
    col_winner = player2
return col_winner
```

I works well for me
But I couldnt set a for loop for row check.
I tried this code block;

```
def row_check():
row_winner = None
rx = []
ro = []
for i in range(game_size):
    for j in range(i * game_size, i * game_size + game_size):

        if matrix[j] == player1:
            rx.append(j)
        elif matrix[j] == player2:
            ro.append(j)

if len(rx) == game_size:
    row_winner = player1
elif len(ro) == game_size:
    row_winner = player2

return row_winner
```

But it checks all numbers in matrix. It should check by row.
How can I do that?

Comment: Using loops for this tasks is a bit inefficient and complicated - but I`d guess it is some kind of class work? Are you specifically bound to the basic functionalities of python or are you allow to use an extended library?

Comment: No, I don't prefer to use extended library :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a code block like this and it worked perfectly.
It was simplier than I thought.

```
def row_check():
row_winner = None
for i in range(game_size):
    if matrix[i * game_size:i * game_size + game_size].count(player1) == game_size:
        row_winner = player1
    elif matrix[i * game_size:i * game_size + game_size].count(player2) == game_size:
        row_winner = player2

return row_winner
```

Comment: or just reset payer 1 = -1 and player 2 = 1, then check the sum ;) Also: use one loop for both if your 'matrix' list is a square.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are bound to the structure used in column_check() and you need 4 in a row for a game_zize of 4; 3 for game_size = 3.
My solution would be like this:

```
def row_check():
    row_winner = ""
    for i in range(game_size):
        ro = []
        rx = []
        for j in range(i * game_size, i * game_size + game_size):
            if matrix[j]==player1:
                rx.append(j)
            elif matrix[j] == player2:
                ro.append(j)
        if rx == range(i*game_size, i*game_size+game_size):
            row_winner = player1
        elif ro == range(i * game_size, i * game_size + game_size):
            row_winner = player2
        return row_winner
```